# Unit testing private methods in connector

Tags: c#, timer, private

I have a connector which send and receive some messages and after invoking method Start() it runs cyclic timer which checks every 5 seconds if any of sent messages was timed out(didn't receive a reply). Should I test this behavior since it's not public?

Answer (score 0):

What would the publicly noticable consequence be? There must be some kind of public behaviour, otherwise the implemented code would be irrelevant. ;-)

Could you implement a time out event or something like that to have an access to the check result?

If you feel like it should be tested, you could also use PrivateObject to get access to non-public members, although"Timer" / threadings tests are always some headache to implement correctly...

Greetings

Andreas